# Limited to 100 result TFS api

Tags: api, powershell

I am using power shell to get data from TFS 2018  (on Premise)
I'm trying to fetch details of our releases  using the TFS API.
I can't seem to return more than 100 entries whatever I try.

```
http://server/tfs/collection/project/_api/_apis/release/releases?api-version=4.0-preview&$top=500
```

Comment: Do you have any documentation on the API that you could share?

Comment: Didn't try it, but AFAIK there are some TFS API REST calls which support pagination. In this case use $top=100&$skip=100 to get the second page and so on...

Comment: adding $skip=100, like this $top=100&$skip=100 gave the same 100 rows only.

Comment: Any sample power shell script using "x-ms-continuationtoken" to the API?